# How to create an animation from a sequence of SVG with identical element ids

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I am trying to create some 2D animations from a sequence of SVG files.

All SVG files have the same number of element and all of the corresponding elements have the same element id. I would like to create animations where each svg is treated as a key-frame and and an animation is produced by interpolating elements with the same id between the key-frames.

I have looked into using snap.svg, but I am not sure how to link objects across different svg files.

Comment: display them in turn as images perhaps.

Comment: I need a solution with a smooth transition between frames.

Comment: You'll need unique ids then if you want to put everything in the same document.

Comment: You could load each image in turn with Snap.load(), but not append the fragment. Grab the path string in the new image fragment, and animate the original image to the new path string (i.e animate the d attr). Once that animation is finished, repeat with the next image (or load them all in create an array of the path strings or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

1. I prepare an svg root element, and inside, one on top of another several svg elements, each with it's `id`.
2. In css I add this: Unless the svg element is targeted `display: none;`

```css
svg > svg:not(:target) {
        display: none;
}
```

3. Supposing that your svg file is: `https://domain/.../rects.svg`, if you  want to target one of the svg elements you use the svg's `id`like this:  `https://domain/.../rects.svg#svg_id`

This is how the root svg would look like:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="-50 -50 100 100">
  <defs>
   <rect id="theRect" x="-30" y="-30" width="60" height="60" fill="none" stroke="red"></rect> 
  </defs>
  <style type="text/css">
 <![CDATA[  
    svg > svg:not(:target) {
    display: none;
    }
     ]]> 
</style>


<svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" x="-50" y="-50" id="_0">
    <use xlink:href="#theRect" transform="rotate(0)"></use>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" x="-50" y="-50" id="_1">
    <use xlink:href="#theRect" transform="rotate(6)"></use>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" x="-50" y="-50" id="_2">
    <use xlink:href="#theRect" transform="rotate(12)"></use>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" x="-50" y="-50" id="_3">
    <use xlink:href="#theRect" transform="rotate(18)"></use>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" x="-50" y="-50" id="_4">
    <use xlink:href="#theRect" transform="rotate(24)"></use>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" x="-50" y="-50" id="_5">
    <use xlink:href="#theRect" transform="rotate(30)"></use>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" x="-50" y="-50" id="_6">
  <use xlink:href="#theRect" transform="rotate(36)"></use>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" x="-50" y="-50" id="_7">
    <use xlink:href="#theRect" transform="rotate(42)"></use>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" x="-50" y="-50" id="_8">
    <use xlink:href="#theRect" transform="rotate(48)"></use>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" x="-50" y="-50" id="_9">
    <use xlink:href="#theRect" transform="rotate(54)"></use>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" x="-50" y="-50" id="_10">
    <use xlink:href="#theRect" transform="rotate(60)"></use>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" x="-50" y="-50" id="_11">
  <use xlink:href="#theRect" transform="rotate(66)"></use>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" x="-50" y="-50" id="_12">
    <use xlink:href="#theRect" transform="rotate(72)"></use>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" x="-50" y="-50" id="_13">
    <use xlink:href="#theRect" transform="rotate(78)"></use>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" x="-50" y="-50" id="_14">
  <use xlink:href="#theRect" transform="rotate(84)"></use>
</svg>
</svg>
```

And this is how I would animate it:

```js
let i = 0; 
function Frame(){
  let n = i % 15;
  requestAnimationFrame(Frame);
  theImg.setAttribute("src", `https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/rects.svg#_${n}`);
  i++
 }

Frame()
```

```css
img{border:10px solid #d9d9d9}
```

```html
<img id="theImg" width="100" height="100" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/rects.svg#_0" />
```

Of coarse, since all those svg elements are in the same file, you won't be able to use the same `id` several times. You'll need uniques `id`s.